# Sweave xtable show column header for rownames

Tags: r, sweave, xtable

I am using an xtable with the option "include.rownames =TRUE". How do I add a column header for the row names?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. Just move the rownames to their own column, name the column, and use `include.rownames = FALSE`.